# python extract domains/subdomains

Tags: python

I want to find domains and subdomains in this string. I used regex to extract non-ascii characters but nothing changed.

```
data = [{"data":
 "0\\x1e\\x82*.extractdomain.com\\x82\\x0ctest.extractdomain.com",
                 "name": "subjectAltName"
            }]

text = ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in data["data"])
```

Comment: `I tried X but it didn't work`: Show us what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: be more specific about the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

- You'll need to split you text by a proper denomination.
- Safely exclude non-ascii, in your case the non-ascii are in turn characters.

**Note:** (Double check if \x1e is one character or 4 characters in length)

```py
import re

def extract_url(url):
    chunks = url.split(".")
    subdomain, domain = ".".join(chunks[:-2]), ".".join((chunks[-2], chunks[-1]))
    return (subdomain, domain)

# splits your text by .com
sites = re.split("(?<=\.com)", data[0]["data"])

# replaces all non-ascii strings (if they're more than 1 char in length)
extracted_sites = [re.sub(r'\\x([0-9a-f]){2}','', site) for site in sites if site]
# replaces all non-ascii strings (if they're single-character)
extracted_sites = ["".join([c for c in site if ord(c) < 128]) for site in sites if site]

print([extract_url(url) for url in extracted_sites])
```

**Output (subdomain, domain):**

```
[('0*', 'extractdomain.com'), ('test', 'extractdomain.com'), ('', 'hello.com')]
```

Comment: This worked. But %, &, +, "etc. can be characters, what can I do to remove them (except -)?